# When using the QGIS2web plugin (OpenLayers3 option), no HTML file created

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web

I'm using the Qgis2web plugin (the OpenLayers3 option), and there is no HTML file  created. The folders appear (Layers, Styles, and Resources). My web browser opens when the folders are created, but it just goes to my homepage, not the map. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please give a little more details so we can help you : which version of QGIS? Which OS? Did you set specific options in the plugin? I just tested it (QGIS 2.8, Ubuntu 12.04), works fine.

Comment: See the instructions for reporting bugs on the Help tab of qgis2web. We need to know what settings you selected, and if that doesn't allow us to recreate the problem, we'll need to know something about your data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of your layers cannot be exported by qgis2web. Removing that layer allows your OL3 export to work again with scale-dependent visibility for all your remaining layers. Investigation took place at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/168. I'll update this answer if we figure out what about that layer caused the failed export.